# UDP socket - C programming Bind and broadcast

Tags: c, sockets, bind

Below is the code I inherited from my company (written by I don't know who) and this code is currently working for my specific scenario which is:
A piece of equipment (signal generator) sends me UDP data, and I need to receive the data, analyze it and sometimes send the equipment a command (based on the analysis). Here is what it looks like:

```
/*********************************************
        **  Communication Struct.
    **********************************************/

typedef struct CtxCom
{
  int                   socket_client;     //socket
  char*                 cmd;               //command
  char*                 recepbuff;         //recepbuff

  struct sockaddr_in    addr_client;       //contains IP and PORT

}CtxCom;


extern struct CtxCom init_Ctx_com ( char* IP_client, const int PORT_client, struct timeval timeout )
{

    CtxCom ClientCom; //define struct
    ClientCom.socket_client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); //Create the socket

    if(ClientCom.socket_client < 0) //Check the creation of the socket
    {
      perror("[Init_Com] socket()");
      exit(errno);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr_me = { 0 }; //create the server struct

    addr_me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); //any incoming IP 
    addr_me.sin_port = htons(PORT_client);
    addr_me.sin_family = AF_INET; //address family

    if(bind(ClientCom.socket_client,(struct sockaddr *) &addr_me, sizeof(addr_me)) < 0) //bind the socket
    {
      perror("[Init_Com] bind()");
      exit(errno);
    }

    //conf equipment side
    ClientCom.addr_client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP_client);
    ClientCom.addr_client.sin_port = htons(PORT_client);
    ClientCom.addr_client.sin_family = AF_INET;

    //timeout
    //setsockopt(ClientCom.socket_client , SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char *)&timeout , sizeof (struct timeval));
    //fcntl(ClientCom.socket_client, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); //set socket to non block

    //Printf info
    printf("[Init CtxCom]");
    printf(" Socket connected and Client[%s:%d] configured *************** \n",
            inet_ntoa(ClientCom.addr_client.sin_addr),
            ntohs(ClientCom.addr_client.sin_port) );

  return ClientCom;

}


/*Write char* cmd of size cmdSize in the socket specified*/
extern void write_client(struct CtxCom CtxCom, char* cmd, int cmdSize)
{
    //adding 0x0a 0x0d to the end of a CMD
    cmdSize+=2;
    cmd[cmdSize-2]='\r';
    cmd[cmdSize-1]='\n';

    //send CMD
    if(sendto(CtxCom.socket_client, cmd, cmdSize, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&(CtxCom.addr_client), sizeof(CtxCom.addr_client)) < 0)
    {
      perror("[Write_client] send()");
      exit(errno);
    }
    else
    {
      //printf( "\n***************SEND OK [%s:%d]******************\n"
        //    ,inet_ntoa(CtxCom.addr_client.sin_addr), ntohs(CtxCom.addr_client.sin_port) );
    }
}




* Give in output the char* strings outStringLLRX with a size of sizeOutStringLLRX*/
extern void read_client(
    /*input*/  struct CtxCom CtxCom, struct timeval timeout,
    /*output*/ char** outStringLLRX, int* sizeOutStringLLRX)
{
    //timeout forced
    //timeout.tv_usec=TIMEOUT_LISTEN_GIII;

    //Define variables
    fd_set      readfs;
    int         loop=1;
    int         i=0, k=0, z=0, z_prev=0;
    int         res;
    char        buf[25500];
    int         sizeBuf;

    //Init variables
    memset(buf, '\0' ,sizeof(buf));
    for(i=0;i<NB_CHANNELS_LLRX;i++)
    {
        sizeOutStringLLRX[i]=0;
        outStringLLRX[i][0]='\0';
    }

    //Make sure buffer is empty
    memset(buf, '\0' ,sizeof(buf));         //empty recep buffer
    FD_ZERO(&readfs);                       //zero testing
    FD_SET(CtxCom.socket_client, &readfs);  // set testing
    
    //block until input becomes available
    res=select(CtxCom.socket_client+1, &readfs, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    switch (res)
    {
        case 0: //timeout
            printf("TIMEOUT error [Read Client] - No data received \n");
            break;

        case -1: //error
            printf("Error [Read Client] \n");
            break;

        default : //streams event
            if( FD_ISSET(CtxCom.socket_client, &readfs) )
            {
                sizeBuf=recvfrom (CtxCom.socket_client, buf , 25500, 0, NULL, NULL); //already now which IP, no need to update
                if ( sizeBuf<0 )  //if <0 => no data => error
                {
                    printf("[Read_Client] Read failed : SizeBuf<0 \n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("[Read_Client] Got a buffer of size %d (round %d) \n", sizeBuf, k);
                    (sizeOutStringLLRX[0])+=sizeBuf;
                    for( z=0; z<sizeBuf; z++) {outStringLLRX[0][z_prev]=buf[z]; z_prev++;}
                }
            }
            break;

    }//switch


  //printf("[Read_Client] final size =%d\n", z_prev);
  /*printf("***************RECV OK [%s:%d]******************\n",
          inet_ntoa(CtxCom.addr_client.sin_addr),ntohs(CtxCom.addr_client.sin_port) );*/
}
```

I have read socket lesson and bind() man, but I'm still wondering: If I have another equipment that sends data on the same subnet, but in broadcast (on the x.255). Can this pollute the socket? and sometimes on the same socket when I'm receiving data from my equipment I received the broadcast instead (or in addition)?

In my case, bind is actually here just to "give a name" to the socket and not to accept any incoming IP address like it's written in the comment?

(Btw, if anything written here is really bad, let me know, I'll be glad to make this code better)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to worry about receiving broadcast packets on the socket. Assuming Linux, `man 7 ip` tells us "Datagrams to broadcast addresses can be sent or received only  when the SO_BROADCAST socket flag is set" (that flag can be set with setsockopt and is documented in `man 7 socket`).

`bind()` is used to select the port to listen to, but also which network interface. The interface is specified by its local address, and `INADDR_ANY` in this case means to listen on all network interfaces (see `man 7 ip`). The socket will receive data from any (valid) IP address on the selected interface(s).

Comment: Okay so without this broadcast flag, it's impossible to see the broadcast traffic on the socket ? 
Bind is creating a kind of endpoint but on the local machine ? And with INADDR_ANY it chooses automatically a local IP available on the local machine ? Is my understanding correct ? Thanks